# How to determine, upon launch, whether the app crashed the last time it quit?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

One of the crash reporter frameworks I've found does it like this: If there exist crash reports in the ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter folder for the app, it determines that a crash occurred before. Then it allows the user to send the developer the crash log. And the finally, it *deletes those logs*.

It is this deletion that is bothering me. It's not acceptable to me. Maybe the user wants to look at those logs later. It is simply rude to the user to just delete his crash logs.

So I'm looking for a better way to determine the crash.

It doesn't really work to store the last read crash logs in the user defaults or the user data, because that would mean that if the user deletes the data and defaults (which he has a right to do whenever he or she wishes), and then launches the app, it will be detected as crashed the last time it was quit. So this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write to a file every time you exit. Read that file every time you open the program. Write a specific integer to the file every time the program is exited that is read every time the program is started.

For example if a 0 is written to a file that may signify a non-crash. Anything else signifies a crash.

Comment: Hmm? And where would I write this file? Are you sure the app gets sent willQuit or such notification methods before it *crashes*? And even if it did, does any of these willQuit methods actually have a parameter saying that the app is crashing or not crashing?

Comment: Oooh, I think I get you. You mean just put a SuccessfulQuit in the user defaults, that is always set to 1 on successful quit, is 0 by default, and gets set to -1 after the app finishes launching. And then if it is actually -1 upon launching it means that I must have crashed. Something like that?

Comment: Yes, and reading/writing the file in a location is up to you.

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking about putting it in the user defaults. No need for any extra file, if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: What happens if there are multiple instances of the application - the new instance will think it crashed last time won't it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way (the registry must be accessed for each app launch though):

```
@implementation ICNRegistry

/**
 * @public
 * @date edited 2014-04-28
 */
+ (ICNRegistry*) registry {

    static ICNRegistry* registrySingleton = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {

        if (!registrySingleton) {

            registrySingleton = [[ICNRegistry alloc] initPrivate];
        }

        return registrySingleton;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

/**
 * @private
 * @date edited 2014-05-09
 */
- (id) initPrivate {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        _appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath =
        [[self cacheRootForClass:[self class]] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
         @"didQuitSuccessfullyIndicator"];
            // (implementation of cacheRootForClass not included)

        // Set _lastAppQuitWasSuccessful:
        [self readPreviousAppSuccessStatusAndStartMonitoringCurrentLaunchQuit];

        // Start monitoring app quit:
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:
         @selector(registerAppWillQuitSuccessfully) name:
         UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Monitoring App Quits

/**
 * @private
 * Checks if a file exists at a specific location. If the file exists, then
 * last app quit was successful and lastAppQuitWasSuccessful will be set to YES.
 * Otherwise, if the file does not exist, lastAppQuitWasSuccessful will be set 
 * to NO.
 *
 * @discussion
 * When app quits in a normal way, a file will be created on app termination, that
 * way indicating successful quit. If the app quits unexpectedly, then the file 
 * will not be written and thus the quit will be indicated as not being successful.
 *
 * @since 2014-05-09
 * @date edited 2014-05-09
 */
- (void) readPreviousAppSuccessStatusAndStartMonitoringCurrentLaunchQuit {

    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    self.lastAppQuitWasSuccessful = NO;

    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:self.appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath]) {

        self.lastAppQuitWasSuccessful = YES;

        NSError* error;
        [fm removeItemAtPath:self.appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath error:&error];

        if (error) {

            ICN_WARN(@"failed to delete 'app quit successful' indicator file at "
                     @"path %@; %@", self.appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath,
                     error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @private
 * @since 2014-05-09
 * @date edited 2014-05-09
 */
- (void) registerAppWillQuitSuccessfully {

    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Create file path if not present:
    NSError* error;
    NSString* dir = [self.appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath
                     stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    [fm createDirectoryAtPath:dir withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                   attributes:nil error:&error];

    if (error) {

        ICN_WARN(@"failed to create dir %@; %@", dir, error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }

    [fm createFileAtPath:self.appQuitSuccessfulIndicatorFilePath
                contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

#pragma mark -

@end
```

Then, for illustration, in my app delegate I do something like this:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {

    // If app did quit unexpectedly (due to crash, reset, etc) last time it was
    // used, then clear all cache to avoid inconsistencies
    if (![[ICNRegistry registry] lastAppQuitWasSuccessful]) {

        [ICNUIViewImageCache clearCache];
    }
}
```

It should be noted that with this solution, the FIRST time the app is launched it will be detected as if it did crash before. If this is an issue, then the file indicator could be created the first time the app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I was looking for a good way to do this and didn't come across one.

Perhaps this will help someone in a similar situation..

I am doing this on Windows, but perhaps it is also possible on osx/linux using named pthread mutexes, though I don't know the policy on how such mutexes are handled if an app is terminated, which is critical to this technique.

The problem with using a single flag is that it doesn't work in the situation where there may be multiple instances of the application:

- App 1 runs.  Sets the 'haven't shutdown properly flag'.
- App 2 runs.  Sees that it hasn't shut down because the flag is set and thinks that there was a crash when there wasn't.

This is slightly tricky to get around and there are probably several ways of doing this but this method appears to work OK so far (on Windows, at least):

Create a global named mutex with a newly generated GUID/UUID as name.
The GUID is different for each instance of the app, so each will have a unique named mutex.
The GUID is written to a file containing a list of GUIDs. 
If the application shuts down correctly then you remove the GUID from the file and the mutex is closed.
If the application crashes or is terminated then the GUID is not removed from the file BUT the mutex is destroyed by the OS without the app having to do it.

When you start the app up, you can run through the GUIDs in the list and call OpenMutex on them and mutexes that don't not exist (GetLastError returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).  Any non-existing mutexes indicate that a crash/termination occurred.
All the GUIDs that have this property can be removed from the list at this point.

An additional thing that you can do is to remove bad GUIDs from the list when you shutdown correctly.
This gets around the following situation:

- App 1 starts
- App 2 starts
- App 1 crashes
- App 2 is successfully shut down
- App 3 is started.

When App 3 is started, it should not post that there was a crash, because the last shutdown was good.

I also implemented a kind of spinlock on gaining access to the file containing the GUIDs that will carry on after a timeout period and not add the app guid to the file.  In such cases it is probably best to let the app run anyway and lose the crash detection, rather than not run the app at all.

Other caveats are to hold on to the file lock when querying and updating the file to avoid race conditions.  On windows, this prevents the use of stl filestreams, as you'll need to truncate the file after reading it whilst still maintaining exclusive access the file.